# jQuery get image link from string

Tags: jquery

Hey all i am trying to get the png link from a string that houses some HTML in it.

The string looks like this:

```
var thecode = '[caption id="attachment_1794" align="alignleft" width="210"]
  <a href="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Screen-Shot-2012-10-30-at-
  8.52.48-AM.png"><img class="size-medium wp-image-1794" title="Difference between and 
  affiliate programs" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Screen-
  Shot-2012-10-30-at-8.52.48-AM-210x300.png" alt="Learn the and affiliate programs" 
  width="210" height="300" /></a> Learn the and affiliate programs[/caption]<p><span 
  style="font-size: small;">An article by CEO of AD, Inc. (AD®), has been published by 
  <a title="Learn the and affiliate programs" href="http://www.mmag.com/articles/85281" 
  target="_blank">M Magazine</a>. The article is titled: "Putting The Right Place." </span>';
```

I have been trying to get the image link via jQuery code:

```
var newString = $('a[href$=".png"]', thecode).attr('href');
console.log(newString);
```

But the example above returns back **SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:**

What would i be missing?

Comment: I do not have this error, which browser are you using ?

Comment: i am using IE version 9

Comment: Are you trying to get the PDF or PNG?

Comment: What was the unrecognized expression?

Comment: @j08691 OOps! Corrected.

Comment: @KevinB The same code as whats in **thecode**

Comment: Here is a JS Fiddle with the error duplicated: http://jsfiddle.net/X3u4H/

Comment: @StealthRT Have you tried removing the first part `[...]` from the string first? I think it's causing jQuery to not parse it as HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var thecode = '[caption id="attachment_1794" align="alignleft" width="210"] <a href="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Screen-Shot-2012-10-30-at-8.52.48-AM.png"><img class="size-medium wp-image-1794" title="Difference between and affiliate programs" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Screen-Shot-2012-10-30-at-8.52.48-AM-210x300.png" alt="Learn the and affiliate programs" width="210" height="300" /></a> Learn the and affiliate programs[/caption]<p><span style="font-size: small;">An article by CEO of AD, Inc. (AD®), has been published by <a title="Learn the and affiliate programs" href="http://www.mmag.com/articles/85281" target="_blank">M Magazine</a>. The article is titled: "Putting The Right Place." </span>';

var newString = $('<div>'+ thecode + '</div>');
console.log($('a[href$=".png"]',newString).attr('href'));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3pkUt/)**

Comment: AH, so thats the reason... the **[** and **]**. Thanks j08691!

Comment: Why does the string need to be wrapped in a `div`?

Comment: @JSuar Due to how jquery parses html, it has to be wrapped in a div otherwise it won't get all of the elements. jquery doesn't handle text nodes at the top level very well.

Comment: Yeah bascially its creating a real temp div element and then only jquery can parse the html.

Comment: For example, you could avoid the error by using `$.parseHTML(thecode)`, but you won't be able to find your target element because it doesn't properly parse the html.